# Send message with SignalR to client(s) from injected (IoC) method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, signalr

I am new with `SignalR` and still a newbie with `IoC Container` `SimpleInjector` and I am wondering if there are any side effects and/or if I'm save with my chosen approach.

In my web app I have a `SetupHub` that invokes a method on an object resolved with `SimpleInjector`. This method may do anything that I'm not aware about. Maybe it contains `Tasks` and it may consume x units of time.

During this Setup process I want to inform the client of the progress. This is my current implementation and it works fine:

```
public class SetupHub : Hub
{
    public void Start()
    {
        // My SimpleInjector resolve wrapper
        IocContainer.Instance.GetInstance<ISetup>().Start(UpdateProgress);
    }

    private void UpdateProgress(double percentage)
    {
        Clients.Caller.updateProgress(percentage);
    }
}


public class Setup : ISetup
{
    public void Start(Action<double> updateProgress)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                              {
                                  updateProgress(10); // Bogus progress
                                  Thread.Sleep(100);  // Simulate x units of time
                                  CreateRoles();
                                  updateProgress(25);
                                  Thread.Sleep(400);
                                  CreateUsers();
                                  updateProgress(60);
                                  Thread.Sleep(200);
                                  CreateRelations();
                                  updateProgress(100);
                                  //CreateRelationGroups();
                              });
    }
}

public interface ISetup
{
    void Start(Action<double> updateProgress);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Service Locator Alert!!

Your `SetupHub` class has a hardwired dependency on the IoC container itself - this is **not** dependency injection. When DI is done right, *you cannot tell whether you're using an IoC container or if you're injecting the dependencies by hand* - because the **only** place in your entire program that *needs* the IoC container, is the *composition root*.

[This is an **anti-pattern**](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/):

> ```
> public void Start()
> {
>     // My SimpleInjector resolve wrapper
>     IocContainer.Instance.GetInstance<ISetup>().Start(UpdateProgress);
> }
> ```

It also seems `IocContainer.Instance` is a *Singleton* instance. *Service Locator* and *Singleton* are two patterns that directly contradict *Inversion of Control* and *Dependency Injection*.

Instead, you should be *injecting* the `ISetup` dependency through the constructor, along with the method you're depending on, like this:

```
public class SetupHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ISetup _setup;
    private readonly Action<double> _updateProgress;

    public SetupHub(ISetup setup, Action<double> updateProgress)
    {
        _setup = setup;
        _updateProgress = updateProgress;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _setup.Start(_updateProgress);
    }
}
```

Wiring this up with the IoC container is going to be tricky, but it could be simplified if the `ISetup` was injected in a factory class' constructor - first we need an abstraction for the `Hub`:

```
public interface IHub
{
    void Start();
}
```

Now let's create a *factory* class whose sole responsibility is to create `IHub` instances:

```
public class SetupHubFactory
{
    private readonly ISetup _setup;

    public SetupHubFactory(ISetup setup)
    {
        _setup = setup;
    }

    public IHub Create(Action<double> updateProgress)
    {
        return new SetupHub(_setup, updateProgress);
    }
}
```

Make that factory an *abstraction*:

```
public class SetupHubFactory : IHubFactory
{
    // ...
} 

public interface IHubFactory
{
    IHub Create(action<double> updateProgress);
}
```

This `IHubFactory` is an *abstract factory* - the client code receives *any HubFactory*, and works against an *abstraction*, instead of being tied to a single specific implementation:

```
public class ClientObject
{
    private readonly IHubFactory _hubFactory;

    public ClientObject(IHubFactory hubFactory)
    {
        _hubFactory = hubFactory;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // hub is of type IHub - ClientObject isn't tied to a specific implementation.
        // inject a new implementation of the `IHubFactory` and no changes needed,
        // this method will create an instance of the new hub implementation:
        var hub = _hubFactory.Create(UpdateProgressBar);
        hub.Start();
    }

    private void UpdateProgressBar(double progress)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

DI *statically declares the dependencies* in your constructors. If a class has too many dependencies / constructor arguments, it's generally a sign that you're starting to break the *Single Responsibility Principle*.

Then you have a composition root / entry point somewhere:

```
public void Run()
{
    // 1. Instantiate your favorite IoC container.
    // 2. Configure your favorite IoC container.
    // 3. Resolve the entire app's dependency graph at once.
 
    // 4. Profit: // 
    var client = _ioc.GetInstance<ClientObject>();
    client.DoSomething();

    /*  */

    // or..
    // go with Poor Man's DI if you don't have a favorite IoC container:
    var setup = new Setup();
    var factory = new SetupHubFactory(setup);
    var client = new ClientObject(factory);

    client.DoSomething();
}
```

It's your IoC container's job to `new` up the dependencies and automagically inject them into all the required constructors when you *ask* for a `ClientObject` ("ask" is important here). It works automagically because all the classes involved in the dependency graph *tell* exactly everything  they need ("tell" is important here); only *infrastructure code* directly works with the IoC container, the rest of the application is blissfully unaware of its existence.

> *Tell, don't ask.*

Also, with DI/IoC you need to follow the *Hollywood Principle*:

> *Don't call them, they'll call you!*
>
> <sub>*(don't call into the IoC container, the IoC container will call into your constructor)*</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Currently, your setup doesn't allow for any cancellation or error handling. The latter is an implementation detail, so I guess you've handled that in the actual code. I would consider the following:

- Return the started task out of `Start`
- Will you ever need to provide a result from the started task? If so, provide an overload for `Func<double,T>`
- Provide cancellation support via a cancellation token (if business logic dictates this is acceptable)
- Provide a `Stop` method that also that can stop the task created by `Start`